# XPath Query in XML using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to use XPath Query in Python while processing XML. I am using minidom which doesn't support that. Is there any other module for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

etree supports XPath queries, just like lxml.

etree is included in the standard library, but lxml is faster.

Comment: Support for XPath is limited in ElementTree though, as quoted in the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support): "This module provides limited support for XPath expressions for locating elements in a tree. The goal is to support a small subset of the abbreviated syntax; a full XPath engine is outside the scope of the module."

Answer (score 3):

My favorite XML processing library for Python is [lxml](http://lxml.de) which, because it is a wrapper around libxml2, also supports full XPath.

There is also [4Suite](http://4suite.org/index.xhtml) which is more of a pure Python solution.

Answer (score 3):

ElementTree is included.  Under 2.6 and below its xpath is pretty weak, but in [2.7+ much improved](http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse(filename)
result = ''

# How to make decisions based on attributes even in 2.6
for elem in root.findall('.//child/grandchild'):
    if elem.attrib.get('name') == 'foo':
        result = elem.text
        break
```

Comment: my python is still there. thanks a lot, friend